# How would I refresh buttons after configuring parent frames in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

This is a project using Python 3.6.2 and tkinter 36

So, the chunk of code posted below is a slightly trimmed version of a UI that I started making. After a bit of bodging and discovering the config method, I had my theme toggle function working.

The code below essentially toggles the background color of the `Label` and `Text` widgets with the `config` method.

This works, however, the buttons turn invisible until I mouseover them.
I've attempted using `update` and `update_idletasks` to no avail (there is the possibility that I haven't been using them correctly, as there was no example posted on usage in my sources.)

How do I update widgets when the parents change?
Is that would be difficult, would there be a less difficult workaround?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.minsize(width=600, height=400)


DarkTheme = ['#102030',
             '#203040',
             '#101010',
             '#f0f0f0',
             ]

LightTheme = ['#c0d0e0',
              '#d0e0f0',
              '#f0f0f0',
              '#101010'
              ]


Theme = DarkTheme

SBar = Label(root, width=22, fg=Theme[3], bg=Theme[0])
SBar.pack_propagate(0)
SBar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

Text = Text(root, fg=Theme[3], bg=Theme[2])
Text.pack_propagate(0)
Text.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def ThemeSet():
    global SBar
    global Text

    SBar.config(fg=Theme[3], bg=Theme[0])
    Text.config(fg=Theme[3], bg=Theme[2])


def SwapTheme():
    global Theme
    if Theme == DarkTheme:
        Theme = LightTheme
        ThemeSet()
    elif Theme == LightTheme:
        Theme = DarkTheme
        ThemeSet()


themetoggle = Button(SBar, text = 'Theme Toggle', command = SwapTheme)
themetoggle.pack()


def AddLetter():
    global Text
    Text.insert(END, "hello, ")
    Text.insert(END, "world")


addletter = Button(SBar, text = 'Add letter', command = AddLetter)
addletter.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, both buttons are always visible for me. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1, @j_4321

Comment: I am using Linux. In addition, why do you use a `Label` for `SBar` while you don't put any text inside it and pack the buttons inside? You should rather use a `Frame` which is meant to contain other widgets.

Comment: @j_4321 Thanks! Changing `Label` to `Widget` amended my issues, I assume this is due to Labels having a foreground, although I could be wrong.

Comment: *`Label` to `Frame`